# How to access email address through Stripe Connect API?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I already have a Stripe Connect page where users can create an Express account, but I don't know how to get the email address from the account. I have the Stripe Account ID, but when I try retrieving it, the email address, name, and address is `null`. Is there anyway to retrieve these? I'm in test mode, so I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching a live mode Express account, with your test mode API keys?

If so, then this is expected, that `email`, `address` and `name` (which for a live account would have real personally identifiable information aka PII there) fields won't be returned in the response when fetching an Account object with testmode API keys, it is intended to limit showing PII for a real account owner.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to get live mode accounts with test mode keys. I figured out another solution, which is just to implement my own form. There is a Persons API but it doesn't seem to work, at least with express individual accounts. I'm connecting my application, so I would think I'd at least be able to get the email address and name, but I guess not.